# How to make recursive copy of files in the same local folder with bash?

Tags: bash, copy, subdirectory

I was recently trying to go through a directory recursively and copy all the files named `file.jpg` to `newfile.jpg` in the same local directory as the original.

I found a way to do that but it's a bit cumbersome and I have reasons to believe it is probably not the best way to go. I thought I would ask before putting this into a script.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cd top_of_source_dir
#copy all file.jpg and append 'newfile.jpg' to the name
find ./ -type f -name file.jpg -exec cp '{}' '{}newfile.jpg' \;

#rename the newly created files to 'newfile.jpg'
find ./ -type f -name 'file.jpgnewfile.jpg' -exec rename file.jpgn n '{}' \;
```

Does anyone have a recipe to do that in one iteration of the source directory?

Comment: You probably want `for f in *.jpg; do echo "$f" "new${f%.*}.jpg"; done`   Change `echo` to `mv` if you are sure the output is correct.

Comment: @val0x00ff This doesn't do a recursion through the source directory, does it? My file can be several levels into the source directory.

Comment: # Jacques Gaudin, no it doesn't but youc an do something like like `find ./ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'for f; do n="new${f##*/}"; echo "$f"  -> "${f%/*}/$n"; done' _ {} +`   Again replace `echo` by 'mv` if you thinkk the result is correct

Comment: Also don't forget to remove the `->` I put there. It was just to visualize the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple answer:

```
find -type f -name file.jpg -print -printf '%h/newfile.jpg\n' | xargs -n2 -d'\n' mv
```

This makes `find` generate two lines per matching entry: old file path and new file path (with `%h` replaced with the directory path).

`xargs` then executes `mv` on every two consecutive lines:

- `-d'\n'` specifies that elements of the input stream are newline-separated, which is the case here;
- `-n2` specifies that `xargs` should read two elements at a time and pass it to the command: if two elements are `foo` and `bar`, then `xargs` will run `mv foo bar`, and then read the next pair, and repeat.

Replace `mv` with `echo mv` to see what commands will it actually execute.

Comment: Thanks I had `xargs` in the back of my mind but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Well you should be because it's very powerful :)

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I added a description of the options I use.